# Defining $\Gamma(x)$ where $x<0$

Tags: gamma-function

Is it possible to define
$$
\frac{\Gamma(a+b-1)}{\Gamma(a-1)} = \frac{\Gamma(1-(a+b))}{\Gamma(1-a)}
$$

$$
s.t. a+b>0 \\ a,i\in \mathbb N
$$

I know $$\Gamma(x)$$ is defined when $$x>0,x\in \mathbb N
 $$
But suppose $x$ is a complex number, can the gamma function be defined for negative values?

Comment: The Gamma function can be extended to a meromorphic function on the entire complex plane, with simple poles at the non-positive integers $0,-1,-,2,\dots$ having residue $\text{Res}(\Gamma,-n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$ for all integer $n\geq 0$. So, yes the Gamma function can be defined for (most) negative values, and in fact most complex values.